# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'json_to_sheet')

Tags: javascript, node-modules

I am getting this error and do not know what to do. I have not used node_modules before, so it would be nice with help.

**my files:**

[image: files]

i am using the test.js file**code:**

```
const XLSX = fetch('xlsx')
  
// array of objects to save in Excel
let binary_univers = [{'name': 'Hi','value':1},{'name':'Bye','value':0}]
console.log(binary_univers)
let binaryWS = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(binary_univers); 

// Create a new Workbook
var wb = XLSX.utils.book_new() 
// Name your sheet
XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, binaryWS, 'Binary values') 
// export your excel
XLSX.writeFile(wb, 'Binaire.xlsx');
```

What i am trying to do is to have data into xlsx, but for some reason it does not know the function "json_to_sheet".

please comment if you know how to fix it! I am also unsure on what Node.js is, so if that is related please explain to me.

Discord:
**Abinesh#6158**

**UPDATE:**
[image: new]

I have done what you said, but i wont still work. DId i do something wrong? (look at the picture)

(i am using the test.js file)

Comment: have you imported the library?

Comment: @AkashJain What do you mean? How am i supposed to do that?

Comment: `import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';`

Comment: @AkashJain I get this error then:
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "xlsx". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Comment: @AkashJain The script tag is also this:
<script type="module" src="test.js"></script>

(just in case this is important i am sending it here)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `xlss` first to your project, open a `terminal` and go to you project path and install the xlss library.

```
$ npm install xlsx
```

[other ways to install](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx)

Once installed, you can use this without any error

```
const xlsx = require('xlsx');
```

**Updated answer**: after looking into your `package.json` , it's clear it's not configured properly, so follow these steps:

1. Create an empty folder and open it in terminal.
2. Type `npm init -y` on the empty folder, once done you should see a proper `package.json`
3. Type `npm install xlsx`
4. Create a new file and name is whatever you like (e.g `myFile.js`)
   and paste your Excel code there.
5. Make an edit in `package.json` on the `script` key, like this

```json
  "scripts": {
    "start": "myFile.js"
  },
```

6. Now you run the code and should not see any error, command to run `node .\myFile.js`

Comment: ```
PS C:\Users\Abine\OneDrive\Dokumenter\VISUAL STUDIOS CODE PROJECTS\WEBSITES\Karan Maama Project> npm install xlsx                      

added 9 packages, and audited 10 packages in 2s

found 0 vulnerabilities
```
This is what i get and i still have the same problem. I am pretty sure i have innstaled i.

Comment: do you see it in your node-module folder?

Comment: What exactly am i supposed to see?

Comment: a folder called `xlsx`

Comment: jupp it is there

Comment: never mind i found your issue, move your test.js to you js folde

Comment: still the same error:
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "xlsx". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Comment: ok try this then `const xlsx = require('xlsx');`

Comment: Hi again, this is the new error i get:

"Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"

For some reason i can't use require, and i dont know why. I tried searching up that error, but cant find a good anwser.

Comment: what's the `type` in your `package.json` ?

Comment: do you mean this:
```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5"
  }
}
```

That is the only thing that is inside of the package.json

Comment: @Abinesh.co made an update to the answer

Comment: Hi again, sorry for the late response. I have updated my question with a picture. Please look into that.

Comment: @Abinesh.co your `package.json` should be outside (where your` index.html` is for reference) same goes to `test.js`, or just follow my updated answer

Comment: Hi! It did technically work, but I have a question. Is there a way for it to export the data from a button in HTML, and so that the user can download the file for on their computer. Because right now I have to write the command into the terminal and the excel file is downloaded into the folder. Do you know how I can do this? (Sorry for the late response, i have been a little busy)

Comment: yes, you should find examples online